# Json Web Token + User Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, jwt

I just implemented Json Web Tokens to my api, but I don't understand how to verify if the user that created the token, is the one that is making the request.

For example, I have the /user/login end point, and I received the user and password for login. Then I create a json web token with the user data inside, and return it. And here is my problem, how do I know that the user that create that token, is the one that is making the request ?.

I found several ways to verify this, for example saving the user-agent + ip of the user and only accept request for that token if the user-agent + ip  is xxx, but I am not really sure that is the best way.

I hope you can help me with some tips,

Thanks for all

Comment: As @pedrofb said, the server issues the JWT, not the client. The client just send it at each request.

Comment: Hi @JIFT, did you check the answers? Remember if one of the answers fits your question, you can mark it as accepted. It is optional

Answer (score 1):

> how do I know that the user that create that token, is the one that is making the request ?.

**Because the JWT includes the user ID and is signed, therefore any alterations to the content will be detected. Possession of the token is proof of authenticity**

The process of issuing  and authenticating with JWT is more or less like this

**Issuing new JWT**

1. User performs and authentication using its credentials
2. The server validate credentials, generate the JWT payload including the user data and some fields such as expiration time or issuer, and signs the token with server private key
3. The client receives the token and store it (in a secure storage).

**Authentication**

1. User sends a request to server. The request includes the JWT, usually in headers or as url param
2. The server validates the signature with the key, and extracts the user ID to know the requestor. If the signature is not valid rejects the request

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pedrofb , that is the flow that I am actually using, but for example what "secure storage" would you recommend ?, like session variable or cookie ?. And I would like to add extra security in same way, to validate that the userID from that token is the one that is making the request.

Comment: You can use localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies. Look at the comparison here https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage. localStorage is vulnerable to XSS attacks, cookies are vulnerable to CSRF, so you would need a CSRF token added to JWT. Also you can protect cookies with HttpOnly if you do not need to read the JWT content at client side. Decide for yourself as you need :)

Comment: The userId is within the JWT `sub` field. You have to add additional security measure if you want the JWT can not be used to complete a full authentication. For example, require the JWT and a CSRF security token issued previously. Other alternative is to use a cryptographic key pair generated in client side, and require client a signature over the payload of the request. The server will validate the signature with the public key (linked to user account). But this option is more complex to implement

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use a standard like OAUTH2 and let the big boys handle security for you? Rolling your own security is usually very difficult to get correct and almost all the major players provide free OATH support.

That said, I'd be hesitant to lead you down a bad path, however I've been in your shoes before so if you must roll your own security, make certain you fully read all of what OWASP has to offer. They offer very detailed threat analysis and also give suggestions that will be invaluable along your journey.

[OWASP Threat Analysis](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Categories)

**EDIT 1**

A good light weight and easy to implement standard is [OpenID](http://openid.net/) which as their banner explains is,

> A Simple Identity layer on top of OAuth 2.0

See here for a very detailed explanation of how it works: 
[OpenID-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

Comment: Hi Joseph, yes this week I implemented this OAUTH library https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/, but it makes me create a lot of tables and I don't really understand why, because this is an api for a website and a app and I think that I don't need all of that. But may be I am wrong. It would be nice if you could tell the flow that you would use with OAUTH to validate a login.

Comment: I've edited the answer to suggest OpenID. Also, the reason for so many tables is that you are installing an OAUTH2 server. Unless you absolutely want to control membership, you don't want that. Instead you want to register your app with a well known provider and use their service (let them sort the headache). There are plenty of resources but I'd start with the OpenID program and work out from there.

Comment: Wow, it looks really Great, but its paid. I am looking a less pro alternative to Develop my self, because it is my own proyect not for the company that I work for.